# Difference between a Drawable and a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

What's the difference between drawables and bitmaps? + What's the meaning of a BitmapDrawable?

I just don't understand why all pictures could be used as Bitmap, and only as Bitmap (or Drawable).

Also, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html):

> A Drawable is a general abstraction for "something that can be drawn." Most often you will deal with Drawable as the type of resource retrieved for drawing things to the screen; the Drawable class provides a generic API for dealing with an underlying visual resource that may take a variety of forms. Unlike a View, a Drawable does not have any facility to receive events or otherwise interact with the user.

In Android's class library, a `Bitmap` is the data *about* a raster image, such as one loaded from a PNG or JPEG file.

> What's the meaning of a BitmapDrawable?

A `Bitmap` does not know how to draw itself; the Android class library developers elected to put that logic in a `BitmapDrawable`.

Comment: well thanks for this clear explanation. Its making more sense now.